# Bad in my opinion vs. low quality

Tags: discussion, down-votes, answers, flagging

In the review queue for low quality answers I came across [this answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/20227/1601). The answer is pretty bad in my opinion, it lacks rigour, etc. Yet it is an attempt to answer the question, not spam or vandalism. We already have downvotes to deal with answers we disagree with.

When should I recommend deletion (in the review queue or via flagging) rather than downvoting an answer?

Comment: It seems like it makes more sense to downvote. flagging is for spam and low quality.

Comment: @EconJohn Please consider posting your comment as an answer. This is a meta question and consensus should provide guidance. My question is about the difference between "bad" and "low quality". Based on your comment the boundary is not clearer to me.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question certainly has the right to do so. Seeing that this is a discussion I hope they will choose to elaborate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this answer on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141857/243394):

> You should **Delete** a post
>
> - If the post is rude or offensive [possibly flag]
> - [ANS] If the answer asks another question
> - [ANS] If an answer is actually a comment (such as asking for more info, thanks!, etc.) [possibly flag]
> - [ANS] If the answer is incomprehensible and you are at least a bit familiar with the subject.
> - [ANS] If the answer duplicates another, better answer to the same question (e.g. a link-only answer where another answer provides the same link with an explanation).
> - [ANS] Is obvious spam (tries to sell you cheap sunglasses) [flag].
> - [ANS] **Note that wrong answers should not be deleted:** deletion is for answers that “aren't even wrong”.

A common theme among these guideline seems to be that deletion is reserved for not-an-answer's.

For the particular answer you linked to, I voted "Looks OK" when I reviewed it, since it does try to address the OP's question, albeit not in a very satisfying manner.

Comment: I'm voting for this. I think it's a good idea to remain consistent with network wide norms when we don't have a good reason for doing otherwise.

Comment: This seems a pretty reasonable interpretation from me as well.